# Python-OpenCV GStreamer warning, and long time running

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, anaconda, warnings, gstreamer

I use Python (version 3.11.5) with Anaconda distribution. I install OpenCV (version 4.6.0) and GStreamer (version 1.18.5) package through Anaconda. I have the code to read a frame of video:

```
Import cv2
Import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
video = cv2.VideoCapture(r"file_name.mov")
number_of_frames = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
print("Number of frames: ", str(number_of_frames))
video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame_id)
ret, frame = video.read()
img = np.asarray(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
fig, axs = plt.subplots()
axs.imshow(img, origin='lower')
plt.show()
```

The code can run normally (on another computer), but it doesn't work fine on my computer. I run with Visual Studio Code on Windows 11. Normally, the code can run within 10 seconds, but for my computer I got a warning and use more than 7 minutes to run it (with the normal result). The warning is:

```
[ WARN:0@0.440] global C:\b\abs_f8n1j3l9l0\croot\opencv-suite_1691622637237\work\modules\videoio\src\cap_gstreamer.cpp (2386) cv::handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: your GStreamer installation is missing a required plugin
[ WARN:0@0.440] global C:\b\abs_f8n1j3l9l0\croot\opencv-suite_1691622637237\work\modules\videoio\src\cap_gstreamer.cpp (2386) cv::handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: your GStreamer installation is missing a required plugin
[ WARN:0@0.440] global C:\b\abs_f8n1j3l9l0\croot\opencv-suite_1691622637237\work\modules\videoio\src\cap_gstreamer.cpp (2402) cv::handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module uridecodebin0 reported: Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in.
[ WARN:0@0.441] global C:\b\abs_f8n1j3l9l0\croot\opencv-suite_1691622637237\work\modules\videoio\src\cap_gstreamer.cpp (1356) cv::GStreamerCapture::open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0@0.441] global C:\b\abs_f8n1j3l9l0\croot\opencv-suite_1691622637237\work\modules\videoio\src\cap_gstreamer.cpp (862) cv::GStreamerCapture::isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created

(python.exe:7476): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 23:01:55.543: Unexpectedly, UWP app `Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2307.45.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe' (AUMId `Microsoft.ScreenSketch_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App') supports 29 extensions but has no verbs
```

I try to search a solution of problem like this, but I still can't find it. I really need everyone's help for this problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by uninstall Anaconda and Python. Then install python again from https://www.python.org/. And install libraries such as NumPy, Matplotlib, pandas, SciPy, OpenCV with `pip install [libraries-name]` in Command Propmt of windows, everything work fine.